# store commas in mysql database

Tags: php, sql, mysql, escaping

I'm trying to store the date in an sql table, but I want it formatted as such:

Month day, year
October 10, 2010
But whenever I do the sql call, the 2010 gets lost. How can I fix this?

```
$eventdate = "October 10, 2010";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tims`.`blog` ( `title`, `date`, `post`, `author`, `approved`) \n"
            . "VALUES (
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title'])     . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($eventDate)) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['TextArea1']) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['author'])    . "', 'False')\n";

//echo $sql;
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why do you want to store a *formatted* date?! You're supposed to store dates in `date` or `datetime` columns, which don't have any formatting. The formatting is only relevant when you want to *output* the date. What type of column are you trying to store it in?

Comment: I would recommend that you store the date as a datetime, rather than as a varchar/text.

Comment: The trick is just to store it in the proper format for a MySQL DATE(`YYYY-MM-DD`), as it will make date functions rather easies on you, and just call DATE_FORMAT on retrieval if you desire other formatting.

Comment: I want to store a formatted date because I don't know any other way. I am just making this up as I'm going and it seemed like a good idea, because that is how the user is gonna input it, and thats the way I want to print it.

Comment: May you also be interested in possibly *querying* based on a date, like "find all posts of 2010"? If so, you're not going to get very far storing dates as plain text. Not knowing how to is a bad reason to do something inappropriately. Learn how to. You're an *engineer* for crying out loud! ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the column width.  You need a VARCHAR(n) as the data type for that column and n needs to be the length of the longest month name of the year + 9.  It's not a good idea to store dates this way if you every want to index or sort them, but it should work.

To see the table structure:

```
show create table `tims`.`blog`;
```

Comment: Thank you. That was my problem, I hadn't made the VARCHAR long enough.
Is there any harm in making it longer than T'll ever need? like say 255, is the database gonna use more memory or anything?

Comment: I generally make my varchar columns 3x the size I expect them to need.  Not sure if this is frowned upon though.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the rest, you must use the date column in a table for the record and then then you have to display it in your application , you just format the retrieved date as you want like "October 10, 2010". Please do not store the date as varchar text, relational database have the simplicity to store date for you and with SQL you can format the date anyway you like to display it.